# clang -o deleted my .c file?

Tags: c, macos, compilation, clang

I stumbled upon [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1994802&seqNum=7) article about clang (I have used gcc), so I followed the instructions to compile a .c file but gave me this error:

```
clang -o File.c test
ld: can't link with a main executable file 'test' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Then I tried to compile again but the file was gone, I couldn't find it anywhere in my Mac.

Is it gone? Is there any chance to get my file back? Thank you.

Comment: To recover your file, if you used emacs as a text editor, see if you have a file called `File.c~` in your work directory.

Comment: To avoid this kind of trouble next time, use version control: subversion,  git... Meanwhile, on Linux, use testdisk or similar recovery tools. Since File.c has been specified as an output argument, there are chances that it has been overwritten and that no tool on earth will return it back to life. Backup...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You followed the instructions wrong.  You want:

```
clang -o test File.c
```

Your command is telling clang to name its *output* `File.c`, using `test` as input.

As to your follow up questions:

> Is it gone?

Yes, almost certainly.

> Is there any chance to get my file back?

Do you keep backups?